# Why would this give out a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I have a method caller addColisionBox and when i call it and setting values to it i get nullpointer at the place im calling it.. I will show some code:

```
    public void addCollisionBox(int x, int y, int arrayNum)
    {
        //Creating a new rectangle at the x & y cord passed in
        rectangle[arrayNum] = new Rectangle(x, y, R_Width, R_Height);
    }
```

And i created inside another class like this:

```
CollisionHandler collision;
....
//CurrentX and CurrentY position to pass into addCollisionBox method and at the array number i
collision.addCollisionBox(currentX, currentY, i);
```

And it says in a message box that Visual C# express give out that: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: you forget collision =  new CollisionHandler();

Comment: Oh im crazy.. How could i forget this..

Comment: Unless there is code initializing the object between the declaration and the method call, you're getting the NullPointerException because you didn't initialize the object.

Comment: Note that in C#, it's a `NullReferenceException`, which is the functional equivalent of `NullPointerException` in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't initalize your `collision` object. You should have something similar to the following. e.g.

```
CollisionHandler collision = new CollisionHandler();
```

...or how ever you are creating/grabbing an instance of your object prior to using it.

Comment: I wil accept this answear in 10 minutes.. I have to wait before accepting apparently.

Answer (score 2):

You have not created another instance, all you have done is create a variable of a given type.

```
CollisionHandler collision = new CollisionHandler();
//                 ^ variable           ^ instance of object
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not created an instance of your CollisionHandler object.  Try something like this:

```
CollisionHandler collision = new CollisionHandler();
....
//CurrentX and CurrentY position to pass into addCollisionBox method and at the array number i
collision.addCollisionBox(currentX, currentY, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
CollisionHandler collision = new CollisionHandler();
```

You've just declared the variable but not set it to anything, hence the null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that `collision` is null when you're trying to call the `addCollisionBox` method on it, thereby causing the null dereference. If it definitely has a value at some stage then you're probably deleting it somewhere, but given the code you've pasted it seems more likely that you just need to create an instance of `CollisionHandler` as it doesn't appear that you're doing so.

```
CollisionHandler collision = new CollisionHandler();
```